# How to explain the different regioselectivity of ketones/imines reacting with LDA?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds, amines

When 1 equivalent of LDA is reacted with, for example, 2-pentanone, you get the thermodynamic (more substituted) product. But when you react butan-2-imine with 1.0 LDA, you receive the kinetic (less substituted) product. **Why?**

I found out that the 2-pentanone reaction conditions included a temperature of around 0 degrees celsius, explaining the thermo product. The reaction conditions needed for the kinetic product would need a temperature of about -78 degrees celsius with more than 1.0 equivalent of LDA base. The reaction condition for the butan-2-imine included a temperature of -78 degrees celsius.

Comment: Well, I found out that the 2-pentanone reaction conditions included a temperature of around 0 degrees celsius, explaining the thermo pdt. The reaction conditions needed for the kinetic product would need a temperature of about -78 degrees celsius with more than 1.0 equivalent of LDA base. The reaction condition for the butan-2-imine included a temperature of -78 degrees celsius.

Comment: Think you answred your own question with your edit.